# Datalab Kernel crashes when creating dummies for a huge dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-bigquery, kernel, google-cloud-datalab

I'm running a 16 cpus/104 gb memory instance on cloud datalab.

When i import a data set with 2000 columns from big query and convert it to a dataframe it works completely fine. The conversion process takes about 90 mins. The size of the file is 3gb and has 200,000 rows.

For the next step, I'm trying to create dummies for all the categorical variables in the data.  I'm using the get dummies function from pandas and as soon as I run it the data lab crashes.

> "the kernel appears to have died. it will restart automatically jupyter notebook"

Is this a memory issue? Will increasing cores help?

Comment: It's likely a memory issue. And no, increasing cores doesn't help your memory issue, increasing RAM does.

Comment: I noticed that this question is also published in [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/900052/datalab-crashing-despite-high-memory-and-cpu), they mentioned to try with this solution posted in [GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9829#issuecomment-362263264) did you try it?